# Cannot find RKJSONParserJSONKit.h

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I cannot import RKJSONParserJSONKit.h. I have followed the RESTKIT install tutorial [RestKit Installation on Xcode 4.x](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x) and it is working very well, but I can't use JSONParser.

In the point the tutorial says **Link Binary With Libraries** in search dialog it can't find these libraries:

```
libRestKitNetwork.a
libRestKitObjectMapping.a
libRestKitSupport.a
libRestKitJSONParserJSONKit.a
libRestKitXMLParserLibxml.a
```

If someone can help me I apreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to link these libraries only if you are installing version 0.9.3. If you are installing the latest version, just ignore it and link **libRestKit.a** instead. Being not able to import *RKJSONParserJSONKit.h* is a different story. Do you try to import it like this?

```
#import <RestKit/RKJSONParserJSONKit.h>
```

This works for me in the latest version of RestKit.

Comment: Great!!! it worked properly! Ive tried other ways but not that. Thanks a lot!!! Well I have another question, Im using RKObjectMapper to perform parser over an JSON reponse collection, that come to me as NSString, and Im gettin this error "Cannot map a collection of objects onto a non-mutable collection." Do it need to pass an collection of my Domain objects? If so, Im new to Objctive C and its classes, how can I do that? Thanks =D

Comment: I think you should create new question with the problem description and the code that you are using.

Comment: Have you tried this in v20? I upgraded and am trying to figure out where the RKJSONParser went.